# Variable passed with mysql query displays odd square brackets when query is echoed

Tags: php, mysqli, geolocation

I am trying to pass the city name taken from a set of reverse geocoded coordinates and then use that city name to query a database. However, when the variable containing the city name is passed in the mysqli query the reverse-geocoded city name (In this case, Vancouver) also includes unexpected square brackets. I cannot explain it.

See code:

```
     echo $query = "SELECT * FROM `business` WHERE `city` = '".$city."'  ";
```

In the console looks like:

```
    SELECT * FROM business WHERE city = ' Vancouver'  []
```

Entire function looks like this:

```
public function get_business_details($phase, $city) {
  include_once "connect.php"; 

  $returnJson = [];
  echo $query = "SELECT * FROM `business` WHERE `city` = '".$city."'  ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data = array( "business_name" => $row['business_name'], "address" => $row['address'], "description" => $row['description'], "identification" => $row['id']);
                array_push($returnJson, $data);
      }
  if($phase=== "0") {          
    echo json_encode($returnJson);
  }
  if($phase === "1") {
    return $returnJson;
  }
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the brackets are printed from `$query` ? It could be `json_encode($returnJson)` too, if my eyes are seeing it correctly.

Comment: Thank you.

I spotted the problem thanks to you. You're right, the brackets are coming from the echo json_encode, and when that is eliminated the only other problem is white space before 'Vancouver'. ...I just removed the whitespace, now everything works.